# What is the right verb for expressing a feeling before correcting someone?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

In a meeting someone says something that's totally wrong from technical perspective. I know what the correct concept is.

I feel the need to correct them. However I want to start with an exclamatory statement expressing my feeling first. Something like

> Mr. X's statement *intrigued* me. Let me clarify that ....

What's the correct verb (if any) in place of *intrigued* just being used as an example here.

It's like I know what he said is wrong, and I want to share the correction for benefit of everyone.

Comment: Mr X's statement troubled me and I felt it needed some clarification.

Comment: There's no particular word for that, because there could be dozens reasons Mr X was wrong…

Comment: I think you mean "start with an [*de*clamatory](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/declamatory) statement"

Comment: not sure any such is necessary.

Comment: Clearly, you were  not intrigued.

Answer (score 1):

The different senses of **pique** that are available

> *pique* verb (used with object) ...
>
> 1. to affect with sharp irritation and resentment, especially by some wound to pride:
>      *She was greatly piqued when they refused her invitation.*
> 2. to wound (the pride, vanity, etc.).
> 3. to excite (interest, curiosity, etc.):
>      *Her curiosity was piqued by the gossip.*
> 4. to arouse an emotion or provoke to action: to pique someone to answer a challenge.

{[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pique?s=t)}

make this an ideal weasel-word here.

Comment: "Picked my interest". Without interest, the OP 's pique might be off.

Answer (score 1):

**Puzzled** or **befuddled** works.

Puzzled -

> B2 confused because you do not understand something:
>
> He had a puzzled look on his face. I'm still puzzled as to why she
>   said that. I'm really puzzled that I haven't heard from Liz for so
>   long.

"puzzled": Cambridge Dictionary https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/puzzled

Befuddled -

> : utterly confused or puzzled : deeply perplexed
>   … somebody may be so befuddled and self-destructive as to miss the point entirely. —Anne B. Fisher
>   … I also believe whites are as befuddled about race as we are … —Nathan McCall

"Befuddled." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 28 Mar. 2018.
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/befuddled

Comment: puzzled or puzzling, yes, befuddled, no. Not in a meeting.

Comment: @Lambie I'm bewildered, whyever not? I searched for "befuddled" and "Congressional Record" as a stand-in for *meeting* and got about 4000 hits. "Puzzled" and "C. R." yielded about 56,000. "Bewildered" and "C. R." netted 50,000. (I  was surprised *bewildered* beat *befuddled*.)

Comment: Ah - *Bewildered* is the older word and was once more common than now. The long history of the C. R. skewed the result. *Bewildered* remains somewhat more common than *befuddled*, but not that much so.